# Delphi XE6 and NotificationCenter only work with APP open

Tags: delphi, notifications, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

When I create an app using this component it just send notifications to Android while APP is opened or when she's in the background because I pressed the home button on the phone, if I close the app or exit using the back button notifications are no longer passed to the cell. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: How can your app *create* new notifications when it is not running?

Comment: @Sir Rufo  Would like WattsUp for example, he is working in the background to notify the user about the messages.

Comment: Android apps don't work in the background, they get suspended.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect for your app to create any notifications if it is not running? Your app needs to be rinning in order to create or post any notivications to the OS.

So now you would probably wanna focus on preventing the app instantly closing when back button is pressed in a way that you notiffy the user that closing the app will prevent its notifications to work and then give your user choice to either close the app or simply keep it workinng in the background.